# expand from daily report to last 7 days

Tags: mysql

I have created a report that shows the monthly active user count on a given day [active user-defined as active in the last 30 days]
I am now trying to create a report that shows the same MAU count per day over the last 7 days

can you please help?

thanks,

Still rusted in SQL.

below the report, I have created for today

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT User_id), Country
->  FROM TABLE 1
-> where activity_date BETWEEN NOW() - INTERVAL 30 DAY AND NOW()
-> group BY Country
```

Comment: just change to `INTERVAL 7 DAY`?

Comment: @tcadidot how would that be 'monthly'?

Comment: After reading your comment, I now understand what 'MAU' means @Strawberry

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way; I may be missing a couple of parentheses and aliases, but you should get the idea...

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT User_id) total
     , Country
     , 't-0' my_range
  FROM TABLE1
 where activity_date BETWEEN NOW() - INTERVAL 30 DAY AND NOW()
 group 
    BY Country 
Union
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT User_id) total
     , Country
     , 't-1' my_range
  FROM TABLE1
 where activity_date BETWEEN NOW() - INTERVAL 31 DAY AND NOW() - INTERVAL 1 DAY
 group 
    BY Country
```